# AngularJS $http post fails

Tags: angularjs, rest

```
I am new to AngularJS, I am from SAP background and as part of my PoC I built my REST services using SAP NW Gateway,I am facing an issue to POST data from Angularjs to my REST services.Please find the below detailed error log

    ***1.      Remote Address:
    10.xxx.xx.xx:8000
    2.      Request URL:
    //host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/USERS/Users
    3.  Request Method:
    POST
    4.      Status Code:
    400 Bad Request
    5.      Request Headersview source
    1.      Accept:
    application/json, text/plain, */*
    2.      Accept-Encoding:
    gzip,deflate
    3.      Accept-Language:
    en,te;q=0.8
    4.      Authorization:
    Basic a2VsYW1yOmoyZDEwMA==
    5.      Connection:
    keep-alive
    6.      Content-Length:
    146
    7.      Content-Type:
    application/json;charset=UTF-8
    8.      Cookie:
    sap-usercontext=sap-client=100; SAP_SESSIONID_J2D_100=R_60WyUyNG2nV1MbhC9QAcKPzyBwwxHkmwsAUFaDBqQ%3d
    9.      Host:
    abcdefgh:8000
    10.  Origin:
    file://
    11.  User-Agent:
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
    12.  X-CSRF-Token:
    _jXDnt2Cdpplpj5zvK3iPA==
    6.      Request Payloadview source
    {UserID:555, FirstName:rajesh555, LastName:kelam555, Email:rajesh555@gmail.com, Phone:9876554433,…}
    1.  Country: "UK"
    2.  Email: "rajesh555@gmail.com"
    3.  FirstName: "rajesh555"
    4.  LastName: "kelam555"
    5.  Phone: 9876554433
    6.  Postcode: "TW18 4BL"
    7.  UserID: 555
    7.      Response Headersview source
    1.      content-length:
    535
    2.      content-type:
    application/json
    3.      dataserviceversion:
    1.0****


Angular Code for Post :
 $scope.addRow = function () {

                           var config = {};                        

                           var pushdata = {'UserID':$scope.UserID, 'FirstName':$scope.FirstName, 'LastName':$scope.LastName, 'Email':$scope.Email, 'Phone':$scope.Phone, 'Country':$scope.Country, 'Postcode':$scope.Postcode};

                           // Sending Notification to User
                           growl.addSuccessMessage("User Created", config);
/*                         $http.post(url,pushdata, {'Content-Type':'application/json'}).success(function(pushdata) {
                                  $scope.resultSet = pushdata.d.results;
                                  alret("Data Posted");

                           }) */                   

                           $http.post(url,pushdata, {headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}}).success(function(data){alert(data);});
                           $scope.resultSet.push(pushdata);
                           $scope.createMessage();
                           $scope.UserID='';
                           $scope.FirstName='';
                           $scope.LastName='';
                           $scope.Email='';
                           $scope.Phone='';
                            $scope.Country='';

                     };

it would be great if some one help me to sort.

*Note: I am a kid in AngularJS...please ignore me and feel free to thought me.

I request to suggest the best URl/Site to learn Angularjs in a better and consistent way.


I thought, if I share the format(XML/JSON) of payload expecting for the POST to perform by my SAP Gateway service  which will helps me to quickly resolve this.Below are the formats of XML/JSON  works for POST.
```

XML Format:
    
    
    host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/USERS/Users('123')
    
    
    Users('123')
    
    
    2014-11-21T15:21:52Z
    
    
    
    
     
    
    123
    
    
    RAJESH
    
    
    KELAM
    
    
    RAJESHKUMAR.KELAM@ABG.CO.UK
    
    
    123456789
    
    
    UK
    
    
    RG4 6SA

JSON Format:
    {
    d: 
    {
    __metadata: 
    {
    id: "host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/USERS/Users('123')"
    uri: "host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/USERS/Users('123')"
    type: "USERS.User"
    }
    -
    UserID: "123"
    FirstName: "RAJESH"
    LastName: "KELAM"
    Email: "RAJESHKUMAR.KELAM@ABG.CO.UK"
    Phone: "123456789"
    Country: "UK"
    Postcode: "RG4 6SA"
    }
    -
    }

Comment: You don't need to add the content type header, angular will sort that out for you. There doesn't look a lot wrong with the post method, it's probably your services you want to look at.

Comment: Hi Ben, I have tried the same you advised earlier to this post but no luck.And I can confirm that my service is working absolutely fine with all the CRUDQ operations from both SAP Gateway client and Chrome REST client.But I am doubting the format it is trying to post is not matching....I saw the error is XML formatting error.

Comment: By default Angularjs will send it JSON not XML. Is your service expecting XML? I don't know how to make angular send XML or even if it can.

Comment: Is there any way that I can see the JSOn format and amend in a way that my service is expecting, Thanks

Comment: Use fiddler or google chrome developer tools to inspect what's being sent to your service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could able to sort out my problem, it is all about formatting the data passing to REST service..

below is the peice of code which works is my case

$scope.addRow = function () {

```
                       var StrUId =  ($scope.UserID).toString();
                       var StrPh =  ($scope.Phone).toString();
                       var pushdata = {"UserID":StrUId, "FirstName":$scope.FirstName, "LastName":$scope.LastName, "Email":$scope.Email, "Phone":StrPh, "Country":$scope.Country, "Postcode":$scope.Postcode};

                       // Posting data
                       $http({
                              method: "post",
                              url:url,
                              data:pushdata,
                              headers: {
                                "X-CSRF-Token": "0XGo8HzpzrhaZxxX83QH9g==",
                                         },
                              dataType : "json",
                              async: false,
                         contentType: 'application/json',
                         success: function(data){
                               alert(data);
                         }
                       });
```

Thanks for the support given 
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

You sure that the url you posting is expecting this data you want to post? You can use POSTMAN extension (in google chrome) and test if you service are ready to receive any data from http.post

Comment: Hi, this is what in my mind...how can I check which format and data it is expecting ....I tested posting data successfully using SAp gateway client and Chrome Adv REST client...it is acceptiing both XML/JSON format too